# Why are the names Rumi and Mevlana respectively used for the famous poet?

Tags: historical-context, rumi

[This famous Persian poet and mystic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumi) was named Jalāl ad-Dīn Muḥammad Balkhī (جلال‌الدین محمد بلخى‎) or Jalāl ad-Dīn Muḥammad Rūmī (جلال‌الدین محمد رومی), where Jalāl ad-Dīn Muḥammad was his actual personal name while Balkhī and Rūmī were [nisbas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisba_(onomastics)) referring respectively to his birthplace and the place where he spent much of his later life.

In the English-speaking world, he is usually referred to as **Rumi** after one of these nisbas. In various Middle Eastern countries (e.g. Turkey), he is commonly referred to as **Mevlana** or some other variant of Mawlānā (مولانا‎) meaning "our master".

**Why have these sobriquets in particular become popular for him?** Nobody refers to him by his personal name; instead we have, in the west, the name "Rumi" meaning "from the western part [of the Persian Empire] which was formerly in the Roman Empire", and, in the Middle East, some variant of the name "Mawlana" meaning "my/our master". How did these names become the standard way of referring to him? And why different names in different countries?

Comment: Mawlana in a sense that he is considered a guide to God, he is considered one who was successful in his spiritual growth and hence can guide others as well. It's worth noting that he himself had a master 'Shams' . Such teachers of spirituality are also known as 'peer' and the disciple ' murid'.

Answer (score 1):

Muslims generally called Byzantine, Turkey, & Anatolia Rum. The name **Rumi** was popular untill very recently in the east as well. [Karim Zamani](https://www.amazon.com/Karim-Zamani/e/B00MY4SB1K%3Fref=dbs_a_mng_rwt_scns_share) who is a famous exegete of Mevlana's work in a lecture says it was very common until somewhat 50 years ago to call him Rumi. But then came a bit strange atmosphere around that name and people saw it as a kind of **Westernization** and therefore avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this could be expanded to make a better answer. Why was the name "Rumi" seen as Westernisation? Is it possible to trace the comparative usage of both names in different countries?